# xcrun/lipo freezes with OS X Mavericks and XCode 4.x

Tags: python, xcode, psycopg2, osx-mavericks, lipo

Been trying to install psycopg2 with either easy_install or pip, and the terminal gets stuck in a loop between xcrun and lipo.

```
sidwyn$ sudo easy_install psycopg2
Searching for psycopg2
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/psycopg2/
Reading http://initd.org/psycopg/
Reading http://initd.org/projects/psycopg2
Best match: psycopg2 2.5.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/psycopg2/psycopg2-2.5.1.tar.gz#md5=1b433f83d50d1bc61e09026e906d84c7
Processing psycopg2-2.5.1.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-dTk7cd/psycopg2-2.5.1/setup.cfg
Running psycopg2-2.5.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-dTk7cd/psycopg2-2.5.1/egg-dist-tmp-4jaXas
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
```

It bounces between xcrun and lipo and is stuck forever in this loop. Would appreciate some insights on this.

I'm on OS X Mavericks 10.9, latest build.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A more appropriate fix is:

```
ln /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo
xcrun -k lipo
```

Why: xfx's fix will likely break being able to use xcode-select to choose your toolchain in future versions of Xcode.

Pre- Mavericks and Xcode 5.x, /usr/bin/lipo seems to be the *actual* location of the *actual* lipo tool (try `cat /usr/bin/lipo` - looks like a big binary). In Mavericks / Xcode 5.x, lipo was moved to XcodeDefault.xctoolchain, and the binary at `/usr/bin/lipo` is a thin wrapper that appears to just call `xcrun lipo` (see `nm /usr/bin/lipo`), which in turn finds the location of lipo based on `xcode-select`.

Probably, new versions of `xcode-select` and/or Mavericks replace /usr/bin/lipo with the wrapper version. If you then try to use lipo with the 4.x toolchain `xcode-select`'d, it won't work, since the tool isn't contained in older versions of Xcode. Luckily, it's still included in iPhoneOS.platform for some reason, else you'd probably have to pull it from an uncorrupted <=10.8 machine.

It looks as if there was a lot of shuffling of tools between Developer/usr/bin and Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin in the 4->5 switch - it wouldn't surprise me if there were similar problems with other less-often-used command line tools as well.

Finally, the fact that xcrun hangs when it can't find a tool seems like an apple bug, plain and simple.

Comment: This q should be tagged with mavericks/xcode/lipo/xcrun and probably not python/etc, as it's a build toolchain issue and not a python issue.

Comment: One other note - if lipo still hangs after the above, `xcrun -k lipo` will clear the cached (incorrect) location. And, awesomely, if you do this WHILE your build is hung, it will instantly unhang.

Answer (score 12):

This one works for me:

```
xcode-select -–install
sudo mv /usr/bin/lipo /usr/bin/lipo.orig
sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/lipo /usr/bin
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem, fixed by replace the /usr/bin/lipo with an old one from Max OS 10.7.

Update:
replace /usr/bin/lipo with /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin will work. You need Xcode application or img file.

Comment: Wonder what kind of repercussions this might have?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is probably upgrading to XCode 5.x.

Comment: indeed.  just had to work this our with a client.  They had the latest and greatest Command Line Tools installed, but an older version of XCode 4.1.x    After we upgraded XCode, we no longer had this issue.  very very weird.

Comment: I'm running Mavericks and had this problem. Upgrading to XCode 6 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I restored `/usr/bin/lipo` from my `TimeMachine` backup (timestamp before updating to OSX 10.9).
Then `XCode` 4.x worked fine, archiving did not hang any more.