# Can't install PIL after Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library, pip, osx-mavericks

I've just updated my Mac OS to 10.9 and I discovered that some (all?) of my Python modules are not here anymore, especially the Image one.

So I try to execute `sudo pip install pil`, but I get this error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/tk.h:78:11: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found

#      include <X11/Xlib.h>

               ^

1 error generated.

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

My Xcode is up-to-date and I don't have any idea. Is it possible that PIL is not yet 10.9 compatible ?

Comment: Not an answer, but have you tried Pillow? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1 - it's a very well supported for of PIL.

Comment: @JamesAddison Pillow 2.2.1 is similarly effected.

Comment: you want `pip install pillow`

Comment: On macos 10.10.5 Yosemite, `pip install Pillow==5.0.0` works, installs `.../site-packages/PIL` .    
(Why 5.0.0 ? See the
[issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3068) ).

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Following worked for me:

```
ln -s  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers/X11 /usr/local/include/X11
sudo pip install pil
```

UPDATE:

But there is more correct solution below, provided by Will.

> open your terminal and execute:
>   `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Your answer has a typo, it's `MacOS10.9.sdk` not `MacOS0.9.sdk`.

Comment: If you also want to have a PIL/Pillow with zlib/png/zip support you also need to do: `ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/zlib.h /usr/local/include/`

Comment: If it does not work, try slightly different directories: `sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers/X11  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/X11
` and then `sudo pip install Pillow`

Comment: instead of making symlinks installing the command line tools (as suggested in another answer) fixes the solution properly.

Comment: the suggested command brings up an error dialog from Apple. First it asks whether I want to Get XCode (which I have) or "Install". I choose install. It pops up a EULA, I accept, then an error dialog comes up:

"Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server."

Comment: @MattFeifarek: Try looking at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server)

Comment: The "More Correct Solution" did not work for me (in fact the command line tools were already installed in the normal way, so I got the same error as in @MattFeifarek's comment).  But the symlink did fix the problem (allowing X11/Xlib.h to be found).  So I think the second solution is only a more correct solution _if it works_!  For the rest of us, the symlink is the better solution.

Comment: I encountered an error  
`Downloading/unpacking pil
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pil
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external pil to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pil
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Usermania/.pip/pip.log`

Comment: ln: /usr/local/include/X11: No such file or directory
I have no /usr/local/include/X11 direcotry?

Comment: Works also for Yosemite OSX 10.10

Comment: Don't mess around with symlinks, run `xcode-select  --install` and you're fine. (as Will mentioned)

Comment: USE THE UPDATE METHOD: xcode-select --install WORKS!

Comment: Although `xcode-select --install`is helpful, I still had to symlink X11 issuing `ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11 /usr/local/include/X11` - JFYI, I was trying to build [Dlib](http://dlib.net) using the included Cmake file (examples), on El Captian (OSX 10.11.1).

Comment: `ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers/X11 /usr/local/include/X11` worked on MacOS Mojave 10.14

Answer (score 102):

open your terminal and execute:

`xcode-select --install`

Comment: The question is not about installing Xcode but PIL... Moreover, I explained that I already had Xcode installed and up-to-date.

Comment: This solves the problem as well (it install the command line tools that are not installed by default with Xcode).

Comment: This is all I needed to do, none of that symlinking stuff.

Comment: @VincentShowcaseWorkshop Xcode does not install the command line tools by default. I had to do this to get past the same problem as the OP's even though I most definitely already had Xcode installed and up to date on Mac OS 10.9.2.

Comment: This fixes the issue with Mac version 10.11.2 (15C50).

Answer (score 34):

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers/X11/ /usr/local/include/X11
```

helps for me!
os x 10.9

```
pip install pillow
```

but! after pip install ...

```
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available
```

and finally i fix it by running:

```
xcode-select --install
```

then reinstall pillow

```
pip install pillow

PIL SETUP SUMMARY
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    version      Pillow 2.2.1
    platform     darwin 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04)
                 [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    --- TKINTER support available
    --- JPEG support available
    --- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
    --- TIFF G3/G4 (experimental) support available
    --- FREETYPE2 support available
    --- LITTLECMS support available
    --- WEBP support available
    --- WEBPMUX support available
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: updated to mavericks yesterday and just today I was starting a project, you just saved me hours of heartache THANKS!

Comment: This I had to do $> ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pillow

Comment: thanks! for 10.10 use: sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers/X11 /usr/local/include/X11

Answer (score 14):

Works for me ( OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 - Python 2.7.9 ) :

```
xcode-select --install
sudo pip install pillow
```

Try this to check it:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open("file.jpg")
image.show()
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is what I did, some steps may not be necessary just for PIL but I needed libpng and others anyways:

1) Run xcode install, use this command or download updates from the app store:

```
xcode-select --install
```

1b) Add the Command Line Tools optional tool, in Mountain Lion this was an option on the xcode Download page, but now you have to register with your apple id and download from: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Look for Command Line Tools (OS X Mavericks) for Xcode

2) Install everything needed for python (using brew), I believe you can use port as well:

```
brew install readline sqlite gdbm
brew install python --universal --framework 
brew install libpng jpeg freetype
```

Unlink/ relink if needed i.e. if upgrading.

3) Install Pip and required modules:

```
easy_install pip 
sudo pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade
```

4) Finally this works with no errors:

```
sudo pip install Pillow
```

**UPDATE** 11/04/14: PIL repo no longer receives updates or support so Pillow should be used. The below is now deprecated so stick with Pillow.

```
sudo pip install pil --allow-external pil --allow-unverified pil
```

**UPDATE** (OLD) : The same thing applies when installing Pillow (PIL fork) and should be mentioned as its quickly becoming a replacement in most cases of PIL. Instead of installing pip in step 4, run this instead:

```
sudo pip install Pillow
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Step 4) may end with sth like `_imagingft.c:73:10: fatal error: 'freetype/fterrors.h' file not found`. But could be resolved following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325473/error-installing-python-image-library-using-pip-on-mac-os-x-10-9.

Comment: are you installing pil or pillow? PIL is deprecated, I'll update this.

Comment: Doesn't matter. PIL or Pillow, it might still be useful for some poeple to resolve symlinking freetype/freetype2 issue. But thanks!

Comment: Yeah I added stuff in step 2 for unlink /link if upgrading. If missing something can you edit and I'll accept?

Comment: sudo pip install pil --allow-external pil --allow-unverified pil 
helped me in 2015

Answer (score 9):

installing command line tools fixed the issue for me

you have to install them separately as they are not part of the packages in xcode now:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=command%20line%20tools#

Comment: I definitely prefer this approach. I hate doing custom symlinking with system packages... you never know what is going to break on the next update...

Comment: That appears to be a bad URL now.

Comment: @MattFeifarek that URL worked for me today. I had to log in with a dev account, but it then took me to the relevant command line tools download page.

Answer (score 8):

Non of those worked for me.. I kept receiving:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

So I found a work around with the following solution:

```
sudo export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
sudo export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
sudo pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```

This way I was able to install.

Comment: This is the one that fixed it for me. If you are running a virtual enviroment, you do not need the sudo command.

Comment: Thank you! This works running a Python virtual environment. I didn't have Xcode currently installed so this saved me the download time.

Comment: This works great for old xcode in 10.8, did it work for Mavericks?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem: Installing pillow failed with `clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]`, installing command line tools failed with `Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server.`, and even after installing the command line tools manually, the compilation of PIL failed.

This happens cause clang under the newest version of xcode doesn't warn on unknown compiler flags, but rather stop the compilation with a hard error.

To fix this, just run `export ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future"` on the terminal before trying to compile (installing pil).

Answer (score 5):

Simply run

`pip install pil --allow-external pil --allow-unverified pil`

Answer (score 3):

**This my steps on mac os 10.9.1**

```
1. sudo su
2. easy_install pip
3. xcode-select --install
4. pip install --no-index -f http://dist.plone.org/thirdparty/ -U PIL
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Homebrew to do the install  http://brew.sh

```
brew tap Homebrew/python
brew install pillow
```

Comment: Hello rchapman. When I run `brew` to install samueljohn/python/pillow, it gives a warning like: `pillow-2.5.1 already installed, it's just not linked`. And before this, there are 15 warnings like: `Could not tap homebrew/python/cpyrit-cuda over samueljohn/python/cpyrit-cuda`. Any ideas why this happens? Or how can I link pillow?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have Command Line Tools installed on your xcode. Then execute:

```
sudo pip install pil --allow-external pil --allow-unverified pil
```

Comment: I was able to install it without command line tools using the Xcode for Mavericks.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the following error

```
building 'PIL._imagingft' extension
_imagingft.c:62:10: fatal error: 'freetype/fterrors.h' file not found

#include <freetype/fterrors.h>

         ^

1 error generated.

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

The solution to this was to symlink freetype2 to freetype and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to install XCode (I don't use it) and I'm loath to fiddle with Application directory.  I've cribbed from the many answers in this post and the following two steps work for me with 10.9.5:

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install pillow
```

It did appear to me strange that I had to use easy_install to install pip.  But pip didn't want to work for me before that (re-)install.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution ... You've to symlink X11 like this `ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11 /usr/local/include/X11` and then `sudo pip install pil` should work.

Comment: not working for me... did you update your xcode before making it to work? did you restart your mac lots of times? this is frustrating me. ughs.

Comment: I did my xcode update before and I restarted my mac even if I'm not sure it's helpful. Maybe the path to your X11 is not the same for you. Try some of the other answers maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Reusing @DmitryDemidenko's answer that is how it worked for me:

```
ln -s  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers/X11 /usr/local/include/X11
```

and then

```
sudo pip install -U PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute the bellow command lines. Works like a charm on Mac OS 10.9.5

easy_install pip

sudo pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade

sudo pip install Pillow

Best, 
Theo

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did:

First upgrade to Xcode 5 (I am running 10.9). Then, execute the following commands in a terminal:

```
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk
$ ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers/X11 usr/include/
```

Comment: A similar answer was given and accepted two weeks ago. I fail to see the additional value of yours...

Comment: Well, this answer has different paths than the accepted one. I added this version as a comment to the accepted answer. The command is `sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers/X11  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/X11`

Answer (score 0):

A more complete solution requires the installation of the Xquartz X11 subsystem that has been built outside of Apple for several years now. Here are the steps I used to get it all working

1. Install XQuartz from http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/
2. Run `sudo pip install pillow`

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer is the right one with `xcode-select --install` but some people (including me) may encounter `Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server`
If you are using beta software (as I am using Yosemite now and had the same problem) you NEED to get the CLT separately since it is NOT included in XCode (even xcode beta)
Head over to developers.apple.com and get CLT tools for your OS ;)

P.S. You don't need XQuartz for PIL or Pillow to work

Answer (score 0):

My machine which was recently upgraded from OS 10.8 -> 10.9 got stuck in a loop between xcrun and lipo.

Rename /usr/bin/lipo to /usr/bin/lipo_broken

Refer to this thread for further information on how to resolve:

[xcrun/lipo freezes with OS X Mavericks and XCode 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667916/xcrun-lipo-freezes-with-os-x-mavericks-and-xcode-4-x)

Answer (score 0):

Install [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) instead:

```
sudo pip install pillow
```

Comment: You still need all the pre-config as you would for PIL

Comment: @radtek no you don't on mac 10.9. Have you actually tried the command before you down-voted my answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote ur answer, i upvoted, but yeah I did try. I actually did this a few times now and I didn't need step 1b actually but everything else I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
ln -s /usr/local/include/freetype2 /usr/local/include/freetype
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pil
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/include/freetype2 /usr/local/include/freetype
```

Comment: Please add a bit more, and explain why he should do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip uninstall pillow
pip install pillow
```

worked for me. I'm running Python 2.7.9 on Yosemite.`import PIL` now works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Installing PIL (Imaging.1.1.7) on Mac OSC 10.10 Yosemite.  I tried numerous fixes recommended here but ran into trouble with each one.  I finally solved this problem by editing the setup.py file such that:

TCL_ROOT = "/opt/X11/include"

which passes the appropriate include path for X11 in the compilation of _imagingtk.c, which was causing the problem for me.  Worked immediately after change.

Answer (score 0):

I've moved from `pyenv` to `virtualenv` and this fixed my problem.

Answer (score -4):

1. ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11 /usr/local/include/X11
2. pip install pil without sudo