# Pip hanging when trying to install PIL on Mavericks

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pip, osx-mavericks, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to install on Mac OSX Mavericks.  It seems to be in an infinite loop because the header at the top of the tab flashes between the titles "lipo" and "xcrun".  Here's a copy of the log: http://pastebin.com/HaBzT2XB.  I originally tried this in a virtualenv, then I tried it out of the env. Then I tried installing pillow, then I tried installing oil from source.  All four of these methods gave the same results.  My searches on Google haven't resulted in anything, So even if someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you already had a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532125/cant-install-pil-after-mac-os-x-10-9)?

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  He got an error, mine just hangs.  I ran the command suggested in that answer but I get: ln: /usr/local/include/X11: File exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it.  Since at the time I wasn't sure if this was going to work, I don't have exact steps of how I did it.  But here's what I remember:
1. installed homebrew
2. used homebrew to install a clean version of python (To replace the non-standard one that comes with OSX)  "brew install python"
3. I added "export PATH=/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:$PATH" at the end of my ~/.bash_profile.
4. I then was able to install pil without problems: "pip install pil"

Answer (score 1):

It is a general problem after upgrading from OS X 10.8 to 10.9. The `/usr/bin/lipo` command hangs no matter how it is invoked.

See also http://d43.me/blog/1769/xcode-4-6-stalls-at-creating-universal-binary-in-os-x-10-9/