# Error Code 1 Installing Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to install the Scrapy module for Python.  I am using the command:

```
pip install Scrapy
```

But I get the following error:

```
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/b4/nrmj5jf105lcv1_kf1yk9gh40000gn/T/pip-build-aNQoXA/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/b4/nrmj5jf105lcv1_kf1yk9gh40000gn/T/pip-B_akAd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/b4/nrmj5jf105lcv1_kf1yk9gh40000gn/T/pip-build-aNQoXA/lxml
```

I've done some research on this, and tried several different solutions [here](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/693#issuecomment-39659057) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063105/installation-scrapy-error-on-mac-10-9-1-using-pip) but to no avail.

Comment: Can you do "pip install lxml --upgrade" and see if that changes anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I needed to install the Xcode command line tools.  (Even if you have Xcode installed.) I have the latest beta of Xcode, but I still needed to install the command line tools.

```
xcode-select --install
```

And then running `pip install scrapy` worked fine.

Comment: Could you at least give the whole command and mention for which OS are you talking about?

Answer (score 6):

you can install it via pip wheel.
Download from here wheel package.
[Scrapy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scrapy)

Then install with

```
pip install wheel       #  to install support for wheel files.
pip install Scrapy‑1.0.3‑py2‑none‑any.whl        # to install the wheel.
```

EDIT: If on ubuntu or another debian based os:

try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev

sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

and then again try to install scrapy.

On Mac Osx :

Install brew package manager from :[Brew](http://brew.sh/)

Then try to use `brew install package_name`

Comment: I installed wheel, and upgraded pip, but now I'm getting the error `Failed building wheel for lxml` and also still get the same error I was originally.

Comment: Are you on linux or windows? Also tell which version.

Comment: The command `brew install scrapy` returns:  `Error: No available formula for scrapy`

Comment: you have to install the dev packages, `python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev` from brew. You can install scrapy from pip or wheel

Comment: Error: No available formula for python-dev 
==> Searching formulae...
==> Searching taps...

Comment: Im on Debian 8.5 and Im using python 3, all I had to do was install what you said but instead of `python-dev` i used `python3-dev`