# Linux pip package installation error

Tags: linux, python-2.7, pip, installation

I am using python 2.7 and trying to install scrapy using pip but get this:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 412, in run_egg_info
    self.setup_py, self.name,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line 12, in 
    import setuptools.version
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in 
    import pkg_resources
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 72, in 
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in 
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: **call**() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Answer (score 3):

Seems there's a problem with your `pip` installation. I have two options for you.

1) Edit file `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py` and replace line

`MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")`

with

`MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR)("marker")`

**OR**

2) Try and upgrade your `pip` installation with

`pip install -U pip setuptools`

Answer (score 1):

[Error Code 1 Installing Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350375/error-code-1-installing-scrapy) talks about the different ways to install scrapy. Your error looks like a dependency issue and [Error Code 1 Installing Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350375/error-code-1-installing-scrapy) explains

```
pip install wheel       #  to install support for wheel files.
pip install Scrapy‑1.0.3‑py2‑none‑any.whl        # to install the wheel.
```

If you use ubuntu, you can also install this via apt:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

Please check out the thread mentioned above for more info. That thread is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem with you. And just type the below command, problem solved:

```
pip install setuptools==33.1.1
```