# Error while installing Scrapy error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

Tags: python, scrapy

I found about scrapy that is a great tool scraping so i tried to install scrapy on my machine, but when i tried to do `pip install scrapy` it installed for a while and threw me this error..

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

I tried to install it in virtual environment but still the problem persists.

EDIT:
here is what i got after the error..

```
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "d:\pycharmprojects\environments\scrapyenv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-arbeqlly\\Twisted\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-jdj93131-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers d:\pycharmprojects\environments\scrapyenv\include\site\python3.5\Twisted" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-arbeqlly\Twisted\
```

any help?

Comment: did you try visiting the suggested url?

Comment: yes i did, but the question is what does scrapy has to do with visual studio

Comment: I would assume scrapy is using an underlying C/C++ library for speed.  I had thought if you installed via wheel, Windows would be prepackaged, but I could be mistaken.  (Also note that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350375/error-code-1-installing-scrapy#32419233 has a similar issue for a Mac user)

Comment: The current recommended way to install Scrapy on Windows is to [use Anaconda/Miniconda with the conda-forge channel](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**
As some one pointed out in the edit,  if you download only the vc_redist.x64.exe it's just 15MB, for that go to "other tools and frameworks" and choose MS Visual C++

solved the problem by installing the tools from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017)

the thing is that some python modules require C++ tools to compile with a python wrapper around, as they are written in C++.

once the setup is downloaded you can select the specific tools or download other facilities provided.

it's somewhere around 4 GB but solves the purpose if in future you need to use some other module which are made in C++.

Answer (score 16):

## Install Using Conda

If you have conda Use: conda install -c anaconda scrapy

Or

## Install Using pip

Download [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted) at this location

```
//Download the whl file of same version as Python version here cp27 means python2.7
pip install Twisted-18.9.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl 
pip install scrapy
```

Comment: Downloading the Twisted file and installing it with pip was definitely the fastest and simplest solution for me

Comment: Holy macaroni this does the trick. No need to download that 4 GB of visual studio.

Answer (score 3):

> but the question is what does scrapy has to do with visual studio

Some python modules require a C/C++ compiler to build. That's why you need Visual Studio.

Quoting from [Scrapy Installation Guide](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/intro/install.html#windows):

> some binary packages that Scrapy depends on (like Twisted, lxml and
>   pyOpenSSL) require a compiler available to install, and fail if you
>   don’t have Visual Studio installed.

Comment: but when i did `lxml` this wasn't the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed the Visual Studio desktop tools for C++ and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Install and use anaconda (A Python packages manager) instead of pip.

Download anaconda from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) then use:

```
conda install scrapy
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Python 2.7 then you have to put Python27 and Pyhton27/Scripts on path and install Visual C++ 14 or above and type `pip install Scrapy` in your cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Installing only the "vc_redist.x64.exe" didn't work for me. 
I downloaded Visual Studio 2019 Community [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) and then chose "C++ desktop developement" and then only the first two boxes (see the following screenshot ont the right):

[image]

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just installed visual studio build tools and the problem get solved. Happy coding!