# Error trying to upgrade Pillow on Mac

Tags: macos, sudo, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to upgrade Pillow on my Mac. When I run `sudo pip install Pillow` I get

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pillow in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pillow-2.3.0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
```

I run `sudo pip install --upgrade Pillow` and I get the following error:

```
copying PIL/OleFileIO-README.md -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/PIL
running build_ext

--- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks
building 'PIL._imaging' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/libImaging
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/Users/edwinzg/School/College/SeniorYear/SpringSemester/rb-master/build/Pillow/libImaging -I/Users/edwinzg/School/College/SeniorYear/SpringSemester/rb-master/include -I/opt/local/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_imaging.o
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Rolling back uninstall of Pillow
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/edwinzg/School/College/SeniorYear/SpringSemester/rb-master/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/Users/edwinzg/School/College/SeniorYear/SpringSemester/rb-master/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
File "/Users/edwinzg/School/College/SeniorYear/SpringSemester/rb-master/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1439, in install
requirement.rollback_uninstall()
File "/Users/edwinzg/School/College/SeniorYear/SpringSemester/rb-master/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 603, in rollback_uninstall
self.uninstalled.rollback()
File "/Users/edwinzg/School/College/SeniorYear/SpringSemester/rb-master/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1855, in rollback
pth.rollback()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'rollback'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Pillow/PIL on Mavericks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334776/installing-pillow-pil-on-mavericks)

Comment: @Hugo What does that mean? Does `sudo pip install --upgrade Pillow` not work then?

Comment: It means this question is a duplicate of [another already asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22334776/724176), and your solution is from an [answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23094087/724176). But good to hear it's now working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

`ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install --upgrade pillow`