# Upgraded to Maverick. Can't access my website's server. Python 2.7 and Django framework

Tags: python, django, macos

I can't access my websites server ever since I upgraded to Mac OSX Mavericks.  Whenever I try running the server, I get this message:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I'm using python 2.7 and django framework.  I've been stumped on this error for a long time.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Mavericks issue. Either:

1. Stop using Mavericks
2. reinstall pillow or PIL like this:

   sudo CFLAGS=-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pillow

(or just PIL, as you prefer)

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall `PIL`, or, better yet, install `Pillow`:

```
sudo pip install pillow
```

EDIT: Not sure why there's a downvote.

But, as ubadub suggested, there's an environment variable you can set (`ARCHFLAGS`, not `CFLAGS`) to fix the issue in Pillow. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334776/installing-pillow-pil-on-mavericks). The short version is that it looks like you should run

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pillow
```

You should probably `pip uninstall pillow` first so that it can be reinstalled.

If that doesn't fix your problem, you should follow the advice in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532125/cant-install-pil-after-mac-os-x-10-9/19545473#19545473), and run

```
ln -s  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers/X11 /usr/local/include/X11
xcode-select --install
```

Then uninstall and reinstall `pillow`.

Comment: sorry...i'm still receiving the same ImportError:

Comment: Try reinstalling Django. Something in native code has been rendered incompatible by the upgrade.

Comment: joshua-tchans-macbook:baseproject joshuatchan$ sudo pip install pillow
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pillow in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...

Comment: I'm still receiving the same message.  I uninstalled Django and installed it again...

Comment: i used this website: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#removing-old-versions-of-django

Comment: is it possible that this is a python issue?

Comment: It's a Mavericks issue, see my post below.