# Is there an easy way to install Pillow on Mac OS X Mavericks Python 2.7?

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I don't want to mess up with Xcode and stuff like that. I've tried a few command line installations but nothing seemed to work smoothly and I can't figure it out. Is there a way for someone who doesn't know a lot about programming to install Pillow? (Bonus points if you can give me an installation file that just does it all for you, that's the way I've done it on my Windows).
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

will install pip for you and then

```
pip install Pillow
```

will install Pillow as @dqiu mentioned.

Comment: Is there anything else I should need to do in order to successfully include the line `from PIL import Image` in a program? Because the installation seems to work but I still get an error `No module named PIL`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's package manager `pip`.

`pip install Pillow` should do the trick to install it.

You can see all the other ways on the [webpage for Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1#installation).

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these steps, as detailed in the [pip documentation](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing.html):

1. Download [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py). Right click on the link and download the file.
2. Open your Terminal
3. Type `sudo python ~/Downloads/get-pip.py` (if the file is in the default `Downloads` folder). Or type the full path to the file.
4. You will be prompted for a password, type your normal user password.

This script will install pip and setuptools (if its not already installed). Now you can proceed to install Pillow and other packages:

```
pip install Pillow
```

If you run into problems, have a look at [Installing Pillow/PIL on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334776/installing-pillow-pil-on-mavericks).

Answer (score 0):

virtualenv worked for me!

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
virtualenv python_script && cd !$
. /activate/bin
pip install Pillow
```