# Can't pip install anything requiring C compilation on OSX 10.10 with homebrew python

Tags: python, macos, pip, osx-yosemite

When I try to `pip install` things that involve C compilation (`Pillow`, specifically) I get an odd error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python'

error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/xt/f2d8vp4j65j2rt71pns6trjw0000gn/T/pip_build_jakob/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/xt/f2d8vp4j65j2rt71pns6trjw0000gn/T/pip-LnL0hW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/xt/f2d8vp4j65j2rt71pns6trjw0000gn/T/pip_build_jakob/Pillow
```

[I posted my `pip.log` for this installation.](https://gist.github.com/c0fd762f3a690a715f85)

I think this problem is due to a combination of OSX 10.10 Yosemite and Homebrew python. Have you experienced this before? ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: What version of Homebrew Python are you using?

Comment: The latest python 2.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to Python 3? Apparently, using Python 2.7 will raise this error while will not. Seen here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1861

Comment: That's my bug report :) - how do I switch to python 3? I have it installed, but how do I make pip use it?

Comment: Ah got me! http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/02/04/how-to-install-python-3-and-pydev-on-osx#2

Comment: I didn't know about `pip3`. However, if I'm working with an application written in python 2, is there anything I can do (other than port it)?

Comment: Check out this as I don't have much experience with the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't install PIL after Mac OS X 10.9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532125/cant-install-pil-after-mac-os-x-10-9)

Comment: I looked at that and it's a different issue entirely.

Comment: did you try python3 -m pip install?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install XCode in order to be be able to compile on OS X.