# Sphinx3 compilation error

Tags: python, macos, cmusphinx

I am trying to use sphinx for the first time. I'm using sphinx3 because I need s3_aligner so I followed many tutorials but none of them got me a result I always get this error :

```
 **configure: error: in `/Users/Bassem/downloads/cmusphinx/sphinxbase':
configure: error: 
  Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main Python library has been
  installed in some non-standard library path. If so, pass it to configure,
  via the LDFLAGS environment variable.
  Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
  ============================================================================
   ERROR!
   You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
   for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them.
  ===========================================================================**
```

I tried so many solution but none of them helped me out all the solutions give the same error .There is a solution for ubuntu which is python-dev for easy linking . I need something equivalent to it on mac or anything to solve me the problem

Here is my config.log:

```
## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
ac_cv_c_bigendian=no
ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_c_const=yes
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_file__Users_Bassem_downloads_cmusphinx_sphinx3____sphinxbase_include_sphinxbase_prim_type_h=yes
ac_cv_file__Users_Bassem_downloads_cmusphinx_sphinx3____sphinxbase_src_libsphinxbase_libsphinxbase_la=no
ac_cv_func_bcopy=yes
ac_cv_func_memmove=yes
ac_cv_header_dlfcn_h=yes
ac_cv_header_inttypes_h=yes
ac_cv_header_memory_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sphinxbase_sphinx_config_h=no
ac_cv_header_stdc=yes
ac_cv_header_stdint_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdlib_h=yes
ac_cv_header_string_h=yes
ac_cv_header_strings_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_stat_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_types_h=yes
ac_cv_header_unistd_h=yes
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
ac_cv_objext=o
ac_cv_path_EGREP='/usr/bin/grep -E'
ac_cv_path_FGREP='/usr/bin/grep -F'
ac_cv_path_GREP=/usr/bin/grep
ac_cv_path_SED=/usr/bin/sed
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_lt_DD=/bin/dd
ac_cv_prog_AWK=awk
ac_cv_prog_CPP='gcc -E'
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_AR=ar
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_DSYMUTIL=dsymutil
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_LIPO=lipo
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_NMEDIT=nmedit
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_OTOOL=otool
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_RANLIB=ranlib
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_STRIP=strip
ac_cv_prog_cc_c89=
ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
ac_cv_search_strerror='none required'
ac_cv_type_signal=void
ac_cv_type_size_t=yes
am_cv_CC_dependencies_compiler_type=gcc3
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes
am_cv_prog_cc_c_o=yes
am_cv_prog_cc_stdc=
cc_cv_attribute_visibility=yes
lt_cv_apple_cc_single_mod=yes
lt_cv_ar_at_file=no
lt_cv_deplibs_check_method=pass_all
lt_cv_file_magic_cmd='$MAGIC_CMD'
lt_cv_file_magic_test_file=
lt_cv_ld_exported_symbols_list=yes
lt_cv_ld_force_load=yes
lt_cv_ld_reload_flag=-r
lt_cv_nm_interface='BSD nm'
lt_cv_objdir=.libs
lt_cv_path_LD=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
lt_cv_path_NM=/usr/bin/nm
lt_cv_path_mainfest_tool=no
lt_cv_prog_compiler_c_o=yes
lt_cv_prog_compiler_pic='-fno-common -DPIC'
lt_cv_prog_compiler_pic_works=yes
lt_cv_prog_compiler_rtti_exceptions=yes
lt_cv_prog_compiler_static_works=no
lt_cv_prog_gnu_ld=no
lt_cv_sharedlib_from_linklib_cmd='printf %s\n'
lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_pipe='sed -n -e '\''s/^.*[   ]\([BCDEGRST][BCDEGRST]*\)[     ][  ]*_\([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\)$/\1 _\2 \2/p'\'' | sed '\''/ __gnu_lto/d'\'''
lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_to_c_name_address='sed -n -e '\''s/^: \(.*\) .*$/  {"\1", (void *) 0},/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[BCDEGRST][BCDEGRST]* .* \(.*\)$/  {"\1", (void *) \&\1},/p'\'''
lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_to_c_name_address_lib_prefix='sed -n -e '\''s/^: \(.*\) .*$/  {"\1", (void *) 0},/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[BCDEGRST][BCDEGRST]* .* \(lib.*\)$/  {"\1", (void *) \&\1},/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[BCDEGRST][BCDEGRST]* .* \(.*\)$/  {"lib\1", (void *) \&\1},/p'\'''
lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_to_cdecl='sed -n -e '\''s/^T .* \(.*\)$/extern int \1();/p'\'' -e '\''s/^[BCDEGRST][BCDEGRST]* .* \(.*\)$/extern char \1;/p'\'''
lt_cv_sys_global_symbol_to_import=
lt_cv_sys_max_cmd_len=196608
lt_cv_to_host_file_cmd=func_convert_file_noop
lt_cv_to_tool_file_cmd=func_convert_file_noop
lt_cv_truncate_bin='/bin/dd bs=4096 count=1'

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /Users/Bassem/downloads/cmusphinx/sphinx3/missing aclocal-1.15'
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
AR='ar'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /Users/Bassem/downloads/cmusphinx/sphinx3/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /Users/Bassem/downloads/cmusphinx/sphinx3/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /Users/Bassem/downloads/cmusphinx/sphinx3/missing automake-1.15'
AWK='awk'
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE='depmode=gcc3'
CFLAGS='-g -O2 -Wall -fvisibility=hidden'
CPP='gcc -E'
CPPFLAGS='-I/Users/Bassem/downloads/cmusphinx/sphinx3/../sphinxbase/include '
CSH=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
DLLTOOL='false'
DSYMUTIL='dsymutil'
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP='/usr/bin/grep -E'
EXEEXT=''
FGREP='/usr/bin/grep -F'
GREP='/usr/bin/grep'
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL='$(SHELL) $(top_builddir)/libtool'
LIPO='lipo'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /Users/Bassem/downloads/cmusphinx/sphinx3/missing makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=':'
MKDIR_P='./install-sh -c -d'
NM='/usr/bin/nm'
NMEDIT='nmedit'
OBJDUMP='false'
OBJEXT='o'
OTOOL64=':'
OTOOL='otool'
PACKAGE='sphinx3'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='sphinx3'
PACKAGE_STRING='sphinx3 0.7'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='sphinx3'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.7'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PERL=''
RANLIB='ranlib'
SED='/usr/bin/sed'
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP='strip'
VERSION='0.7'
ac_ct_AR='ar'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
ad_backend=''
ad_files=''
ad_libs=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE='#'
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep='_no'
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin15.3.0'
build_vendor='apple'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdata='./.DS_Store ./BN_AM_HUB96-97.doc ./BN_AM_HUB96-97.htm ./cmdhelp.txt ./doxygen.cfg ./doxygen.main ./images/rarrow.gif ./index.html ./models.html ./rarrow.gif ./s3/falign.fig ./s3/falign.gif ./s3/feat.fig ./s3/feat.gif ./s3/hypseg.txt ./s3-2.htm ./s3-2.pdf ./s3-2.ppt ./s3-2_files/buttons.gif ./s3-2_files/error.htm ./s3-2_files/filelist.xml ./s3-2_files/frame.htm ./s3-2_files/fullscreen.htm ./s3-2_files/master01.htm ./s3-2_files/master02.htm ./s3-2_files/master03.htm ./s3-2_files/master03.xml ./s3-2_files/master03_image002.gif ./s3-2_files/master03_stylesheet.css ./s3-2_files/outline.htm ./s3-2_files/pres.xml ./s3-2_files/preview.wmf ./s3-2_files/script.js ./s3-2_files/slide0001.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0001_image001.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0004.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0005.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0006.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0007.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0008.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0009.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0010.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0011.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0012.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0012_image003.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0015.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0015_image004.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0015_image005.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0015_image006.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0015_image007.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0015_image008.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0016.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0016.xml ./s3-2_files/slide0016_image009.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0016_image010.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0016_image011.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0016_image012.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0016_image013.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0016_image014.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0016_image015.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0016_image016.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0016_image017.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0016_image018.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0016_image019.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0016_image020.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0017.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0017.xml ./s3-2_files/slide0017_image021.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0017_image022.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0017_image023.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0017_image024.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0017_image025.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0017_image026.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0017_image027.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0017_image028.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0017_image029.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0017_image030.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0017_image031.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0018.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0018.xml ./s3-2_files/slide0018_image032.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0019.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0020.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0020_image033.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0021.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0021_image034.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0022.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0022_image035.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0023.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0023_image036.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0024.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0024_image037.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0026.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0026_image038.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0027.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0028.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0028_image039.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0029.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0029.xml ./s3-2_files/slide0029_image040.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0030.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0030.xml ./s3-2_files/slide0030_image041.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0031.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0031_image042.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0032.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0032_image043.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0033.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0034.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0034_image044.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0035.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0035_image045.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0036.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0036_image046.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0037.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0037_image047.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0038.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0038_image048.gif ./s3-2_files/slide0039.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0040.htm ./s3-2_files/slide0041.htm ./s3-4.pdf ./s3-4.ppt ./s3-5.ppt ./s3-6.ppt ./s3_codewalk.html ./s3_description.html ./s3_fe_spec.pdf ./s3_overview.html ./sphinx3.3-6.ppt ./sphinx3.4.code.tracing ./sphinx3.5_refactoring.note ./sphinxman_FAQ.html ./sphinxman_manual.html ./sphinxman_misc.html'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
epdata='./chan3-dither.cepview ./chan3-logspec.cepview ./chan3.cepview ./chan3.logspec ./chan3.mfc ./chan3.raw ./ep.mdef ./ep.result ./means ./mixture_weights ./variances'
exec_prefix='NONE'
hmmdata='./8gau.6000sen.quant ./feat.params ./mdef ./means ./mixture_weights ./mllr_matrices ./test-align-mllr.out ./test-conf.confhypseg ./test.align.mllr.out ./test.align.out ./test.align.phseg ./test.align.wdseg ./test.allphone.allp ./test.allphone.match ./test.allphone.matchseg ./test.allphone.mllr.allp ./test.allphone.mllr.match ./test.allphone.mllr.matchseg ./test.allphone.phone_tg.allp ./test.allphone.phone_tg.match ./test.allphone.phone_tg.matchseg ./test.allphone.phone_tg.mllr.allp ./test.allphone.phone_tg.mllr.match ./test.allphone.phone_tg.mllr.matchseg ./test.dp.hyp ./test.dp.ref ./test.dp.simple.log ./test.mode1369.dump ./test.subvq ./transition_matrices ./variances'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin15.3.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /Users/Bassem/downloads/cmusphinx/sphinx3/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
lmdata='./README ./align.correct ./an4.cls.probdef ./an4.ctl ./an4.ctl.platform_independent ./an4.ctl_lm ./an4.dict ./an4.phone.dict ./an4.phonelist ./an4.tg.phone.arpa ./an4.tg.phone.arpa.DMP ./an4.tg.phone.arpa.FST ./an4.tg.phone.arpa.FST.SYM ./an4.tg.phone.arpa.lm_convert ./an4.ug.cls.lm ./an4.ug.cls.lm.DMP ./an4.ug.cls.lmctl ./an4.ug.fsg ./an4.ug.lm ./an4.ug.lm.DMP ./an4.ug.lm.FST ./an4.ug.lm.FST.SYM ./an4.ug.lm.lm_convert ./args.an4 ./args.an4.test ./args.an4.test.cls ./args.an4.test.fsg ./args.an4.test.mllr ./args.an4.test.win32 ./filler.dict ./pittsburgh.bigendian.mfc ./pittsburgh.bigendian.raw ./pittsburgh.lat.gz ./pittsburgh.littleendian.abcd ./pittsburgh.littleendian.mfc ./pittsburgh.littleendian.raw ./pittsburgh.littleendian.slf ./pittsburgh.nbest'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sphinxbase='/Users/Bassem/downloads/cmusphinx/sphinx3/../sphinxbase'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''
tidigitsdata='./cepstra/man/man.ah.111a.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.1b.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.2934za.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.35oa.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.3oa.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.4625a.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.588zza.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.63a.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.6o838a.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.75913a.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.844o1a.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.8b.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.9b.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.o789a.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.z4548a.mfc ./cepstra/man/man.ah.zb.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.1b.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.276317oa.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.334a.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.3z3z9a.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.48z66zza.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.532a.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.5z874a.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.6728za.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.75a.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.84983a.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.8a.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.99731a.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.o69a.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.ooa.mfc ./cepstra/woman/woman.ak.za.mfc ./dictionary ./fillerdict ./test.2.digits.fsg ./test.digits.fsg ./test.iso.digits.fsg ./tidigits.length.1.regression ./tidigits.length.1.result ./tidigits.length.2.regression ./tidigits.length.2.result ./tidigits.length.arb.regression ./tidigits.length.arb.result ./wd_dependent_phone.cd_continuous_8gau/mdef ./wd_dependent_phone.cd_continuous_8gau/means ./wd_dependent_phone.cd_continuous_8gau/mixture_weights ./wd_dependent_phone.cd_continuous_8gau/transition_matrices ./wd_dependent_phone.cd_continuous_8gau/variances'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "sphinx3"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "sphinx3"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.7"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "sphinx3 0.7"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define STDC_HEADERS 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define STDC_HEADERS 1
#define HAVE_MEMMOVE 1
#define HAVE_BCOPY 1
#define RETSIGTYPE void
#define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
#define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
#define HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY 1

configure: exit 1
```

Comment: Your `config.log` is not complete, you can find more details in complete log. Message tells you need to install Python

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I can't place all the log here it's too large

Comment: You can put it somewhere else and give here a link

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_4-uXdR2xQ3eWhBek91SzR2QlE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your error is `clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python'`, solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365470/cant-pip-install-anything-requiring-c-compilation-on-osx-10-10-with-homebrew-py

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I  followed that solution but i get the same error and here is my latest log:: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_4-uXdR2xQ3eWhBek91SzR2QlE/view?usp=sharing