# Error installing PIL library for Python

Tags: python, xcode, python-imaging-library, failed-installation

After installing xcode I executed `pip install Pillow` and the last code strings say:

```
In file included from _imagingtk.c:19:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/tk.h:78:11: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found

In file included from Tk/tkImaging.c:52:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/tk.h:78:11: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
#       include <X11/Xlib.h>
                ^

1 error generated.
1 error generated.

Building using 4 processes

cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_imagingtk.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/Tk/tkImaging.o -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib -L/usr/X11/lib -L/usr/lib -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/PIL/_imagingtk.so -framework Tcl -framework Tk

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_imagingtk.o'

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/Tk/tkImaging.o'

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-YMhwsU-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build/Pillow
Storing complete log in /var/root/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Comment: PIL is deprecated; you should use the replacement, [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#mac-os-x-installation)

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this

Comment: @Mikhaylova after installing Xcode did you run the command 'xcode-select --install'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you uninstall PIL first?

Try:

```
pip uninstall pil
pip uninstall pillow
brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2
pip install pillow
```

See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem is that Xcode's Command Line Tools is missing. To fix it, just run

```
xcode-select --install
```

on your terminal. A dialog will pop up, accept and Xcode's CLT will be installed.

See it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19817768/2752041).

Answer (score 1):

PIL is deprecated, use Pillow instead.

To install Pillow:

```
 pip install Pillow
```

Comment: Thank you Riccardo, I tried this but again the same error...I wonder what this X-code is

Comment: @Mikhaylova did you install the X-code developer tools?

Comment: @Mikhaylova you can do it using the command 'xcode-select --install' from the terminal shell

Comment: following your instructions I successfully installed xcode, but I still have problems with Pillow, now it generates new errors when I try to install it. If you don't mind I can copy them here and maybe you can help me :)

Comment: @Mikhaylova ok update your question with the new errors

Comment: Did you uninstall PIL first? Try pip uninstall pil, then pip uninstall pillow, then brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2, then pip install pillow. See https://pillow.readthedocs.org/installation.html

Comment: @Mikhaylova: Great! I've posted this as an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/).

`X` (or `X11`) is a (the default) *nix window system, which some *nix software that can be compiled on a Mac relies upon.

The problem appears to be that PIL and Pillow appear to assume you want `Tk(inter)`, which in turns relies on `X`. If you don't want fancy dialog stuff for your image processing, there should be a way to turn that off, though that may require a manual installation.

Alternatively, perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19545473/707650) may be of use; but that still requires `X` to be installed, and just fixes a bad link.

Answer (score 0):

Installing SDK headers worked for me

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

For more information see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes#3035624

Comment: Make sure the headers you try to install correspond to your macOS version.