# How can I get status of make command in OS X?

Tags: macos, compilation, makefile, tesseract

I'm trying to compile tesseract-ocr on my Mac 10.9 but It gets stock at:

```
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libtesseract.dylib" && ln -s "libtesseract.3.dylib" "libtesseract.dylib")
```

It really takes a long time and I don't know if it is doing anything useful so is there any way I can get status of it's progress or at leas see what it is doing?

here is the lisf of commands I run to get here:

```
svn checkout http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ tesseract-ocr
cd tesseract-ocr
sh ./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

By the way it takes my CPU activity very high that my MacBook fan is turned on. I'm also using iTerm as my shell.

Comment: That command shouldn't take any time really I wouldn't think. You can see what `ps` or `top` says is running and using all your cpu though.

Comment: Yea Etan I also think it shouldn't. here is a screen shot of my terminal if that helps 
http://tinypic.com/r/i53dqa/8

Comment: That doesn't tell us anything your paste in the post didn't. What does `ps` or `top` say is running and using your cpu?

Comment: this is top: http://tinypic.com/r/2chpbv9/8 and this is ps: http://tinypic.com/r/2ltj1xz/8

Comment: Is it normal? Because all of my make threads are in sleeping mode.

Comment: That appears to be xcrun taking most of the cpu. I don't know why that might be. What doe `ps -faxww` say for the `make` tree of processes?

Comment: I hope this is the part you want to take a look at http://i61.tinypic.com/2yuy99c.png

Comment: If you hit control-d in the window where you are running make do things proceed?

Comment: No it doesn't. It just prints a ^D on my console.

Comment: Ok. That was a long shot. Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667916/xcrun-lipo-freezes-with-os-x-mavericks-and-xcode-4-x help?

Comment: Oh Thanks dude, you did a grate job. that worked. add it as an answer if you don't mind.