# sudo gem install compass - stuck at "checking for ffi.h..."

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, compass

Im running terminal on Mac OSX 10.9.5 and had no problems installing the following:

- Brew 0.9.5
- Ruby 2.0.0p481
- Sass 3.4.9
- npm  2.20
- Yeoman
- Bower 1.3.12
- Grunt-cli 0.1.13

After typing `sudo gem install compass -V` it installs a bunch of files but get's stuck here:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150116-1042-1pd2lzv.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h...
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: This is not the appropriate forum for this type of question.  Take a look at the Programmers forum on StackExchange.

Comment: Just found the fix

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667916/xcrun-lipo-freezes-with-os-x-mavericks-and-xcode-4-x